# Use Post ID in functions.php

Tags: php

I have the following code in my `functions.php`. It works great: when a booking is made, it emails me. Simple.

*However*, I'd like it to send me the post ID for that booking rather than just a 'Hello World!' message. Help?

```
function add_to_system() {

  // get post meta
  // $email = get_post_meta('',$post_id)
  // $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
  mail('michael.mcgurk87@yahoo.co.uk', $post_id.' Hello', 'World!');

}

add_action('booked_new_appointment_created', 'add_to_system', 99);
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only posting an alternative answer despite the question being about a 3rd-party plugin, whose source code isn't even freely available, because I don't believe the accepted answer is likely to be a good solution.

It's not documented on their website, but a [comment from the developer](https://codecanyon.net/item/booked-appointments-appointment-booking-for-wordpress/9466968/comments?page=50&filter=all#comment_12081430) states:

> These would all be considered custom requests, which our free support
>   doesn’t handle. What’d you want to do is probably hook into the
>   “booked_new_appointment_created” action which comes with the
>   Appointment ID (which you can use to pull down meta fields, etc.) —
>   That’s all the direction I can really offer you regarding these custom
>   coding questions.

Which implies that callback functions for the `booked_new_appointment_created` hook receive the appointment ID as an argument:

```
function add_to_system( $appointment_id ) {
    mail( 'email@example.com', 'My subject', $appointment_id );
}
add_action( 'booked_new_appointment_created', 'add_to_system', 99, 1 );
```

Doing it this way is far more reliable, as you can be certain that the ID of the appointment you're using is the ID of the appointment that triggered the action, and not some other post or page that might be the 'current' post in the global state.

This is a good rule of thumb for all hooks: Use the arguments passed to callbacks wherever possible instead of global variables.

Comment: Jacob - amazing! You were right. No harm to original answer but it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_the_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) rather than global $post;

```
get_the_ID()
```

Update Like this

```
function add_to_system() {
   mail("michael.mcgurk87@yahoo.co.uk","My subject",get_the_ID());
}
add_action('booked_new_appointment_created', 'add_to_system', 99);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I do `$post_id = get_the_ID();` and it doesn't store anything in my email.

Comment: See updated code which uses get_the_ID in replace of global $post;

Answer (score -1):

try with this :

```
function add_to_system($appointment_id) {
   mail("michael.mcgurk87@yahoo.co.uk","My subject",$appointment_id);
}
add_action('booked_new_appointment_created', 'add_to_system', 99,1);
```

let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Wow - that worked a treat. Thanks so much, @Chetan. Have a good one! :)

Comment: Have you verified this? How do you know that the global $post variable is the post for that booking? And not the confirmation or product page? Where does booked_new_appointment_created fire? Using the global post variable is almost always a bad idea. The callback function apparently receives the appointment ID as an argument: https://codecanyon.net/item/booked-appointments-appointment-booking-for-wordpress/9466968/comments?page=50&filter=all#comment_12081430 Us that.